# Enum values and valueOf

Tags: java, enums

```
public enum ProgramOfStudy {
    ComputerScience("CS"), AutomotiveComputerScience("ACS"), BusinessInformatics("BI");

public final String shortCut;

ProgramOfStudy(String shortCut) {
    this.shortCut = shortCut;
}
public static ProgramOfStudy getByShortCut(String shortCut) {

    for (ProgramOfStudy program : ProgramOfStudy.values()) {
        if (ProgramOfStudy.valueOf(shortCut).equals(program))
            return program;
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

When calling the method getByShortCut like this: getByShortCut("CS") i keep getting an error: "No enum constant ProgramOfStudy.CS" What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is thinking with your compiler instead of with your head. Change `ProgramOfStudy.valueOf(shortCut).equals(program)` to `program.shortCut.equals(shortCut)`.

Comment: how different is getByShortCut from valueOf???

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Instead of looping and getting tangled up with complicated equals conditions, why not apply a bit of Java 8 to this problem?

```
public enum ProgramOfStudy {
    ComputerScience("CS"), AutomotiveComputerScience("ACS"), BusinessInformatics("BI");

    public final String shortCut;

    private static final Map<String, ProgramOfStudy> shortCutMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<>() {
        {
            Arrays.stream(ProgramOfStudy.values()).forEach(v -> put(v.shortCut, v));
        }
    });

    ProgramOfStudy(String shortCut) {
        this.shortCut = shortCut;
    }

    public static ProgramOfStudy getByShortCut(String shortCut) {
        return shortCutMap.get(shortCut);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(ProgramOfStudy.getByShortCut("CS"));
    System.out.println(ProgramOfStudy.getByShortCut("ACS"));
    System.out.println(ProgramOfStudy.getByShortCut("baasda"));
    System.out.println(ProgramOfStudy.getByShortCut("BI"));
}
```

If you run this snippet of code, it will print:

```
ComputerScience
AutomotiveComputerScience
null
BusinessInformatics
```

It is preferrable to use a map in this case instead of a loop with string comparisons. There is only one loop at initialisation in this case and then never again. It is not a good idea to have loops with string comparisons at every query of the `getByShortCut` method.

Answer (score -1):

if you need another option where you can get ridd of the map then do

```
public class StackOverF {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World1");
        System.out.println(ProgramOfStudy.getByShortCut("CS"));
        System.out.println(ProgramOfStudy.getByShortCut("CSI"));
    }
}

public enum ProgramOfStudy {
    ComputerScience("CS"), AutomotiveComputerScience("ACS"), BusinessInformatics("BI");

    public final String shortCut;

    ProgramOfStudy(String shortCut) {
        this.shortCut = shortCut;
    }

    public static ProgramOfStudy getByShortCut(String shortCut) {

        return Arrays.stream(ProgramOfStudy.values())
            .filter(v -> v.shortCut.equals(shortCut))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
    }
}
```